# Math in rails view simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, view, simple-form

I have a view that has simple form inputs for several integers that I want to total - but I can't figure out how to do it. Obviously this doesn't work

OK to clarify this is a view form for the household model in haml (household doesn't have an @ because I'm using decent exposure)

```
= simple_form_for household do |f|
  %td= f.input :income1
  %td= f.input :income2
  %td= f.input :income3

  %td  Total Income #{household.income1.to_i + household.income2.to_i + household.income3.to_i}
```

I want to update the total as the user types in Income
How do I do get the total?

Comment: Really vague question. Maybe provide some context. Do you have a form for a certain model that has these attributes? Does what you have work so far (without the total income). If you do do have a model, what happens in the controller, how is your model instantiated?

Comment: do you want the income1,income2 and 3 to be displayed as well for total try defining attr_accessor :total on ur model and do this on view `f.input :total ,:val => (f.object.income1 + f.object.income2 + f.object.income3)` FYI This just a rough sketch out try reading the doc the syntax more of less like that describe but wont bet on it completely

Comment: I edited the question - it was a little vague - this is only part of the form - I also put it in Haml - My thinking is I might need ajax

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out  - this works but it doesn't display a total until it updates. I guess I need Ajax to do it live